# Domain storytelling system

Tags: domain-driven-design

I want to create a website for selling and buying stuff. When a user offers to buy a product and the seller accepts the offer is getting a notification that the product is sold to him and the product's status is changed to sold. How would one visualize this with domain storytelling?

Currently, my story looks like this but I don't like how the notification looks like it comes from the seller but the seller doesn't do anything because the notification is sent automatically and not sent directly by the seller. Same problem for the status of the product.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ready options:

- You can view the story as saying that the offer updates the status and sends the notification
- You can explicitly model that there's some process (I've seen gear icons used to denote this) watching for accepted offers and updating the status and another (or possibly the same, though beware of multiple changes in one process) process watching for accepted offers and sending the notification